# Set date input format for vue-moment

Tags: javascript, vue.js, web-applications, momentjs

I'm using [vue-moment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-moment) to format date in my app but I don't seem to be able to get it to accept the input format so that moment can parse. My api returns this date format:

```
2019-01-01 24:00:00 GMT
```

I set the (input) format and output it like so within a `v-for`:

```
{{ [ date, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss z" ] | moment("subtract", "5 hours", "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss A") }}
```

The error:

```
Could not build a valid `moment` object from input.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the timezone `z` confuses moment js so I omitted it by using `[ ]` like so:

`{{ [ date, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss [GMT]" ] | moment("subtract", "5 hours", "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss A") }}`